# Cannot run Nuitka in Windows

Tags: python, python-3.6, nuitka

I downloaded Nuitka from http://nuitka.net/pages/download.html ( http://nuitka.net/releases/Nuitka-5.1.281.win-amd64.py36.msi ) and installed it. The installation ran all right without any errors. Python 3.6 is installed on the computer. However, I now cannot find Nuitka's folder and it is also not there on start menu. It is also not found as a command when typed at command prompt.

Where is the problem and how can it be solved? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If the Windows installer isn't working for you, you can always try `pip install nuitka`, which I've run successfully using Anaconda on Windows 10.